# How to stop a form from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am validating my form using jQuery as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=subdomain]').keyup(subdomain_check);
    $('input[name=password]').keyup(password_strenght);
    $('input[name=c_password]').keyup(password_check);
    $('input[name=email]').keyup(email_check);

    $("#install").submit(function(e){
        if(!subdomain_check() || !password_strenght() || !password_check() || !email_check()) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

});
```

Now the issue here is how do I prevent the form from submission if the rules are not met?
When I click the submit button nothing should happen.

Thanks

Here is the whole `script` : http://pastie.org/8812743

Comment: How about `return false`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(formSelector).on('submit', function(){
    return subdomain_check() && password_strenght() && password_check() && email_check();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#install").submit(function(e){

    if ($("#subdomain_check").valid() == true && 
        $("#password_strenght").valid() == true &&    
        $("#email_check").valid() == true)
    {

        $( "#form_id" ).submit();

        return true;            
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following way:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onClick="return funEverythingOK();" />
```

In funEverythingOK(),Check for everything is filled well,Here in this function,Return true ,if everything is ok,else false